# Opening applications within XMonad on start-up within different workspaces

Tags: haskell, xmonad

When starting up I want to launch specific applications within a given workspace. I've tried the following, but all three applications are launched within workspace 1 only:

```
myStartupHook :: X()
myStartupHook = composeAll [ spawnOn "1:web" "firefox"
                           , spawnOn "3:music" "spotify" 
                           , spawnOn "4:chat" "slack"]

main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar"
    xmonad $ defaultConfig
        { modMask    = mod4Mask
        , workspaces = ["1:web","2:mail","3:music","4:chat","5:dev","6:tmp1","7:tmp2","8","9","0","-","="]
        , startupHook = myStartupHook
        , manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
        --, layoutHook = myLayout  -- Use custom
        , layoutHook         = avoidStruts  $ layoutHook defaultConfig
        , handleEventHook = handleEventHook defaultConfig <+> docksEventHook
        , logHook    = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                       { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
                       , ppTitle  = xmobarColor "green" "" . shorten 20
                       }
        }
```

Any suggestions? I'm using XMonad v0.15